# Lighttpd vhost setup

Tags: virtualhost, lighttpd, vhosts

**tl;dr** - How do I reference the conditional regex matches?

I am looking for the simplest vhost setup, but what I am trying doesn't work.

I want:

```
http://example.dev` => /var/www/dev/example/
http://website.dev` => /var/www/dev/website/
```

I have tried:

```
server.document-root = "/var/www/"
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.+)\.(.+)$" {
        server.document-root += "%2/%1/"
}
```

What my method resolves to:

```
Path: /var/www/%2/%1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the %1 %2 syntax only works with [mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite). I can't confirm that, but I've only ever used it with mod_rewrite.

A mod_rewrite solution would be the following:

```
server.document-root = "/var/www/"
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(.+)\.(.+)$" {
        url.rewrite-once = ( "(.*)" => "/%2/%1$1" )
}
```

Which should effectively act as if your document root has moved.

*This is untested

Comment: Simple solution, exactly what I wanted. Thanks.